# how to create buttons which can be acciable in multiple activites in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, audio-player, android-music-player

I am creating a music player app the below are list of activities:

- WelcomeActivity
- SongsListActivity
- MusicPlayActivity
- SongsListActivity will display list of songs available, on click of item it will take you to MusicPlayActivity and which will trigger SongService which in turn play song in background.

The below is MusicPlayActivity

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <include layout="@layout/musicpanel"></include>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The below code is for musicpanel which is included in MusicPlayActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play"
    android:id="@+id/playPause"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stop"
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playPause"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/playPause"
    android:layout_marginLeft="67dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="67dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If the user click back button from MusicPlayActivity we need to display SongListActivity so here I want to display musicpanel.

My question is what is the best practice to create musicpanel?

Right now I am including it in xml but on each activity I need to set listeners for all components of musicpanel (like play, pause, next, previous) every time

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to say musicpanel should be avaible in SongListActivty as well as in MusicPlayActivty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Create a reusable widget. Make it use your player layout, setup listeners, etc. Then add it everywhere you need.
2. Move your player to a notification. It would be accessible from any place in your app. Notifications are quite simple and have to be in the notification area, but you can mix this solution with 1.
3. Move to fragments or views. Your player could be placed above main layout using FrameLayout or RelativeLayout. This is my preffered solution.
4. Move your player to a floating window. It's how the floating Facebook message's head is done. Tricky to do, but nice when done properly.

Usually it's done in 1/2 or 2/3 way as these combinations reduce code duplication and are quite easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think its best for you.Using **PageViwer**  .

1:make 2 fragments.
(1)firstActivity
(2)SecondActivity

2:Use PageViewer in your xml layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.8"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/windowbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is viewPager Instance in your Main Activity.

```
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());

    mAdapter = new MultiPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            viewPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

and here is Multipager adapter

```
   public class MultiPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public MultiPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new FirstFragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new SecFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 2;
}
```

}